# Large number of [Time Wait] Process name

Tags: windows, tcp, process, time-wait

For the past few days, I have noticed strange activity in my network connections. A large number of connections of the [Time Wait] process.

[Screen from TCP_View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b87y7.jpg)

I tried to find some older posts on the subject but found nothing like this. If anyone has encountered something like this I would appreciate information.